# Spring Bcrypt is stateless and doesn't need a secure random?

Tags: mysql, database, spring, spring-security, bcrypt

I have **two doubts** about Spring Security BCrypt:

1. Does Bcrypt need a strenght and secure random to be safe?
2. What best data type to persist in MySQL (BINARY vs CHAR)?

---

About first doubt, I read many tutorials and I found always the same configuration (default)

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

So, can I consider this configuration stateless? Doesn't need to use a strenght and secure random for my web service generates differents hashes from the default configuration?

---

And about second doubt, has Bcrypt hash lenght always 60? So, is better to use CHAR(60) or BINARY(60) in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security is open source. Here's the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java/) for the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`

If you don't pass in a `SecureRandom` it just creates a new one. This is fine from a security standpoint. You could pass in your own for performance or test-ability reasons.

If you don't pass in `Strength` it uses `GENSALT_DEFAULT_LOG2_ROUNDS` which is 10, which is reasonably safe. You could pass in this value for peace of mind.

The database schema for Spring Security suggests a `varchar(50)` for the `password` column, however it looks like 60 is correct, for bcrypt anyway.

I'd use a `char`/`varchar` over a `binary` as it's easier to read (visually).

Comment: Fine, if Spring generates a new SecureRandom, each web service (multiple instances) will have a different SecureRandom, right? This is not a problem?
How Spring suggests `varchar(50)` if I have a password with lenght 60? Database will truncate my password.

Thanks McGuigan